# Singleton Swift Shared [String]

Tags: ios, swift, singleton

I am trying to access the same [String] in two ViewControllers. The first one is setting the array and the second ViewController want to get the array.

Here is the singleton class.

```
class SavedPostsBox{
var postNames: [String] = []

class var sharedInstance : SavedPostsBox {
    struct Static {
        static let instance : SavedPostsBox = SavedPostsBox()
    }
    return Static.instance
}  
}
```

In the first ViewController I the do this:

```
SavedPostsBox().postNames = savedPostName
```

And In the second I do this:

```
savedPostName = SavedPostsBox().postNames
```

The problem is that when I check the sizes in the different classes it is always 0 in the second but not in the first. I tried a lot of different methods and search everywhere but this solutions seems to work for a lot of other people but not for me.

Comment: *Hint:* The `sharedInstance` property is defined, but nowhere used in your code ...

Comment: Thanks, but still not working

Answer (score 2):

You have to get your sharedInstance.

```
SavedPostsBox.sharedInstance.postNames = savedPostName
```

Ans use it everywhere, instead of instances of SavedPostsBox